# Getting NoSuchAlgorithmException when creating a directory on SFTP server via JSch

Tags: java, jsch

I am using JSch to SFTP files to my server.

In Rational Application Developer (RAD) all works as expected.

Outside of RAD, running via bat file I am connecting to SFTP server without any issues but when trying to create directory I am getting following error message:

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DH KeyPairGenerator not available

What do I have in my RAD jdk that I don't have on my machine when running it via bat file? Obviously, it can create connection so my bat file can access `jsch-0.1.51.jar` but it is missing some other jar in my `C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6\bin` that is include in RAD jre.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that

- Your JDK has one of the JAR files (see below) that contain the KeyPairGenerator class?  
   I documented what JAR files contain this class below.

  The CLASSPATH is set to include the path to one of the above JAR files?

  Your JAVA_HOME is set ?

According to findJAR.com, the KeyPairGenerator class is contained in these JAR files:

```
rt.jar
org.osgi.foundation-1.0.0.jar
org.osgi.foundation-1.2.0.jar
```

I searched for `rt.jar`:

- The `rt.jar` file is in my ANT lib directory.

  The `rt.jar` file is also in the `jre/lib` subdirectory of my JDK directory.

If you don't have a containing JAR file anywhere, then try adding the ANT lib directory to your CLASSPATH.

---

This test ANT project can be used to verify SSH is working:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
    <project name="ServerSSH" default="dist" basedir=".">
      <target name="dist">
        <echo message="TEST BEGINNING"></echo>
        <sshexec host="svr1"
                 username="user1"
                 description="Test connection"
                 keyfile="c:/.ssh/id_rsa"
                 trust="true"
                 command="echo CONNECTION SUCCESS FOR SERVER SVR1"
                 failonerror="true"/>

        <echo message="TEST END"></echo>

      </target>

    </project>
```

This test can be invoked as follows:

```
    set JAVA_HOME=c:\progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
    set ANT_HOME=C:\ant
    set ANTLIB=c:\ant\lib
    set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\lib;
    ant -d -lib %ANTLIB% dist -f SSHTEST.xml
```

By running a test, you can verify whether SSH for JAVA will work outside of the project.

Comment: Yes, i have rt.jar in C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6\lib and in my bat file I am setting PATH: set PATH=.;C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6\bin;%PATH%

Comment: In my RAD lib folder rt.jar is older and smaller in size and I actually tried replace rt.jar file in C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6\lib with rt.jar file from RAD lib folder ad when I did that, my program wouldn't even launch.

Comment: My rt.jar is this size: 26868873

Comment: If your server is OpenSSH, are you sure the OpenSSH is at least version 2.8?  Lower versions don't support the DH algorithm.

Comment: For more info on the OpenSSH (server-side) issue (if the version is too low, the problem may not happen until you try to use JAVA), see this URL:

Comment: I have  no issues when running it in RAD, the issue I am having is running outside of RAD. My server set-up is not a problem since I can run my program in RAD without any issues...

Comment: Can you find out whether RAD has anything in the CLASSPATH that you are not including.  Set JAVA_HOME to the JAVA distribution in RAD.

Comment: You should also do an independent test, outside your project, but still on your PC, to make sure SSH from JAVA will work.  I do a test in ANT to make sure SSH is working.  That is what I do.  I will post the test ANT task to this page.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is: Be careful when setting java.ext.dirs to include your JARs

http://peterttseng.blogspot.com/2008/09/be-careful-when-setting-javaextdirs-to.html